# What does the phrase "swashbuckling makeover" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

I hope someone would help me understand the meaning of the phrase "swashbuckling makeover" in the following sentence:

Or discover hidden treasure in Pirate Cove – plus a swashbuckling makeover. <sub>([source](https://apps.apple.com/kw/story/game-essentials-temple-run-2/id1478163405))</sub>

The sentence is from the description of the game Temple Game 2.

I am confused whether the makeover is of the game or of the character in the game. Also, I am not sure if the phrase has an idiomatic connotation that I am not aware of.

Comment: You would need to provide a little more context. Otherwise it's "I shot a rhino in my pajamas" all over again.

Comment: It could be either. Nothing about the "rules of English" tells us whether the reference is to the ***player*** or the ***game*** getting a "makeover", but *pragmatically* it's probably the latter. Whatever - it's Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: Having read the original source, it doesn't even make sense in context. Maybe there was an intervening sentence that was deleted before going up on the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the text alone, it is insufficiently clear which is meant.

Luckily in this case, the picture above that description depicts someone looking a bit like a pirate, running along a beach with washed up crates, cannons, and an octopus tentacle, with a jolly roger on a shipwreck in the distance:

[image: https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Features123/v4/19/21/a2/1921a25d-559e-6bd3-d69d-2fbd555d8383/pr_source.png/736x0w.png]

I would say in this particular instance, the character *and* the game get a makeover. But from the text alone, it's not clear.

As for the '*swashbuckling makeover*' idiom, it means making things look *[pirate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pirate)y*